Installing geopandas in a QGIS Plugin?
I'm trying to install geopandas for use in a QGIS Plugin.

create a venv
install geopandas
add site-packages to path
import geopandas

# sys.executable - path to qgis python interpreter 
# venv_path - path to the virtual enviroment
# venv_pip_path - path to venv pip
# venv_site_packages_path - path to venv site packages

import sys
import subprocess
from importlib import import_module

subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "venv", "--copies", venv_path], check=True)
subprocess.run([venv_pip_path, "install", "geopandas"], check=True)
sys.path.insert(0, venv_site_packages_path)
import_module("geopandas")

This results in the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sam/test/pandas/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 923, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/sam/test/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import is_numpy_dev
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 923, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/sam/test/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.22.4
your numpy version is 1.21.5.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.22.4 to use this pandas version

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 923, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/sam/test/geopandas/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas._config import options
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 923, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/sam/test/geopandas/_config.py", line 109, in <module>
    default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
  File "/home/sam/test/geopandas/_config.py", line 95, in _default_use_pygeos
    import geopandas._compat as compat
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 923, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/sam/test/geopandas/_compat.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 923, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/sam/test/pandas/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: C extension: None not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext' to build the C extensions first.

The import part here is
ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.22.4
your numpy version is 1.21.5.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.22.4 to use this pandas version

...so reload numpy, hopefully fetching the correct version from my venv_site_packages_path
from sys import modules
import importlib

importlib.reload(modules['numpy'])

ends in tears
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 169, in reload
    _bootstrap._exec(spec, module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 619, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/sam/test/numpy/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from ._globals import _NoValue, _CopyMode
ImportError: cannot import name '_CopyMode' from 'numpy._globals' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/_globals.py)

I'm out of ideas?
this module might be overriding the inputs?
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 923, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)


pip uninstall numpy  then pip install numpy

or this pip install --upgrade numpy

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The venv has the correct version of numpy (1.26.something) but this isn't the version imported, maybe due to the module noted at the end of the question?
I have also tried pip installing geopandas in the QGIS python instance, this was my global (/usr/bin/python3). And removing all but the venv path from sys.path to no avail.
